# ActionController::RoutingError in Rails Development Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm having a similar issue to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519997/actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-get-assets-images-control-t), but none of the solutions are working for me.

In my Rails 4.0.3 app, I consistently get the following error:

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/javascripts/underscore-min.map")
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.0.229/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.0.229/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
```

I will also occasionally get similar errors when trying to load other assets (images, etc.), but not for all images; this one is the most consistent. This problem occurs on my local server, in the development environment.

I've tried setting `config.serve_static_assets = true` in my development.rb file, as well as `config.serve_static_files` in case there's a Rails version issue. I've also tried running `rake assets:precompile`.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Please let us know exactly which file cause this error.

Comment: Or show the code which embed image in your view.

Comment: I've added the first few lines of the stack trace for this error... is that helpful?

Comment: Yes Thanks Please have a look at the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Every JavaScript contains sourcemaps file. So basically this error indicate that our JavaScript's sourcemaps file is not loaded in the asset pipeline. And I don't think we need to load .map file in asset pipeline so you can remove .map file line from your JavaScript file. You can find these code in your javascript file .

```
 /*
 //@ sourceMappingURL=yourjs.min.js.map
 */
```

One of the javascript file in your assets pipeline contains this .map file mapping. After removing this line this error will disappear.

Ref: [what is .map file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21719713/2681997)

I hope this answer solve your problem

Thanks

Comment: Worked like a charm. I commented out the reference to the source map and  my problem was fixed. Thank you ABPrime!

Also I appreciate the link to reference materials on the subject of .map files. :)

Comment: @NicolasGarcia: My pleasure. Please accept the answer.